# Filtering with AngularJS within an Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been beating myself up over this for the past two days and I cant find a solution. I'm trying to filter a set of articles based off of their tags. I've used an ng-repeat to repeat the article and display the data coming from my API. But cant seem to get the filter correct.

Here is an example of the Article Object

```
{"id":"05390344-57f8-4f2a-ada0-0705edacd0ef","type":"Article","title":"Lorem title","topics":[{"Id":"bb2a6222-34b1-4abd-8d19-c07eb7ff4d0c","Name":"Pajamas"},{"Id":"7f752e06-092b-473a-9f4e-b79796c7ab7b","Name":"Undies"},{"Id":"bd533c42-90e9-4dce-9316-e3be6c8fc55c","Name":"Briefs"}],"synopsis":"<p>Lorem Ipsem synposis</p>","date":"August 20, 2014","time":"9:28 AM","source":"Localhost","url":"#"}
```

My controller contains

```
    $scope.filterTopics = {};

    function getChecked(obj) {
        var checked = [];
        for (var key in obj) if (obj[key]) checked.push(key);
        return checked;
    }

    $scope.searchFilter = function (row) {
        var topicChecked = getChecked($scope.filterTopics);
        if (topicChecked.length == 0)
            return true;
        else {
            if ($scope.filterTopics[row.topics])
                return true;
        }
    };
    $scope.$watch('cards', function (cards) {
        $scope.count = 0;
        angular.forEach(cards, function (card) {
            if (card.filterTopics) {
                $scope.count += 1;
            }
        })
    });
```

My view to create the ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="article in articles | filter: searchFilter">
```

Then I have checkboxes that I can click to pass search filter the topic Id

```
ng-model="filterTopics['@topic.Id']
```

Any help would be great!!!!

Solution was to add a for loop to grab each object

```
for (var i in row.topics) {
    if (topicChecked.indexOf(row.topics[i].Id) != -1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: filter logic doesn't use array of filtertopics when array has length. ng-model syntax shouldn't have quotes around variables.

Comment: hrmmm if I remove the quotes then the variables do not get passed... any ways I added a for loop to pull out each object.

Comment: I can only speculate unless you post a JSFiddle or Plunkr ;)